# Best way to integrate a chat bot using JSON Feeds

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am planning to develop a chat bot type of conversation using an API. The user information is converted to JSON and the response too is in JSON format. Since the API is stateless each conversation needs to pass the whole data from beginning in JSON API request. My plan is as follows:

The conversation data is passed by ajax to a php file and store values in an php session array and then json_encode and pass to API and get response from API which is passed back after json_decoding to the conversation page.

Is this the better way or is there anything else better. Will the current plan have any scaling issues ??

Or can it be done using jQuery? Not so familiar with Node.js since i am a newbie. Please provide valid suggestions.

Comment: json encode and decode is the right way and u can use ajax jquery without refresh page it will help

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 will it have any scaling issues. Can it be done using Jquery without using php ??

Comment: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/07/10-very-good-reasons-to-stop-using-javascript/

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 Nice article. Thank you.

Comment: wt u r tried ,and if it is not solve by u can upload

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 No issues with code, thank you. I was just seeking advise on whether it is the best way to move forward.

Comment: S of course u can continue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160989/discussion-between-jeevanswamy21-and-pamela).